# Prevent selection of rich text box in Visual Basic 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, textbox, richtextbox, highlight

In my visual basic program, I have a rich text box that returns either a success or an error message for the login process. This has relevant colours and is a read only text box too.

My issue is that you can still highlight the text within the box. I have the following properties set `readonly = true` and `disabled = false`. I cannot disable the rich text box as it will not allow the use of text colour.

Answer (score 0):

This code might help you: add selection changed event handler to your rich text control (code in C#):

```
private void richTextBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Move the cursor to the end
            if (this.richTextBox1.SelectionStart != this.richTextBox1.TextLength)
            {
                this.richTextBox1.SelectionStart = this.richTextBox1.TextLength;
            }

        }
```